How to force set useragent when using Puppeteer emulate function?
I am using puppeteer emulate function to emulate an Iphone device. However, I need to use the user agent passed to the function. How do I set only the device user agent field?
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 13 Pro'];
(async () => {
    console.log(iPhone)
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 250});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(iPhone);
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
    await page.screenshot({
      path: 'test3.png',
      type: 'png',
      fullPage: true
    })
    console.log(await page.title())
    await browser.close();
})();

In the above code, it sets the standard useragent as per puppeteer. The result for the above is
{
    name: 'iPhone 13 Pro',
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML,       like Gecko) Version/15.4 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1',
    viewport: {
     width: 390,
     height: 844,
     deviceScaleFactor: 3,
     isMobile: true,
     hasTouch: true,
     isLandscape: false
  }
}

I tried passing the user agent while getting the device from puppeteer but it dint work. If I try to set it directly in 'iPhone' it fails. Any recommendation on how to force set the user agent while get the device from emulate function?

const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 13 Pro']; TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'iPhone 13 Pro'). What Puppeteer version are you using? I don't see any calls to setUserAgent so you might want to add that. Presumably you're doing it after setting the emulation.

I don't see any attempt at using setUserAgent, or code you're using to verify the current user agent, but it works as expected for me:
import puppeteer, {KnownDevices} from "puppeteer"; // ^22.10.0

const ua =
  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";

const getUA = async page => {
  await page.goto("https://whatmyuseragent.com/", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });
  return page.$eval("#ua", el => el.textContent);
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const p = console.log;

  p("1. default UA and VP:");
  p(await getUA(page));
  p(await page.viewport());

  p("\n2: using the device config object with modification:");
  await page.emulate(KnownDevices["iPhone 13 Pro"]);
  p(await getUA(page));

  p("\n3: overriding a property on the device config object:");
  const custom = KnownDevices["iPhone 13 Pro"];
  custom.userAgent = ua.replace("123", "124");
  await page.emulate(custom);
  p(await getUA(page));

  p("\n4: setting UA from string:");
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  p(await getUA(page));

  p("\n5: making sure VP is still emulating iPhone 13:");
  p(await page.viewport());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

The output is:
1. default UA and VP:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
{ width: 800, height: 600 }

2: using the device config object with modification:
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

3: overriding a property on the device config object:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

4: setting UA from string:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

5: making sure VP is still emulating iPhone 13:
{
  width: 390,
  height: 844,
  deviceScaleFactor: 3,
  isMobile: true,
  hasTouch: true,
  isLandscape: false
}

Looks all good to me!
See this thread for the import adjustment. I'm not sure what version of Puppeteer has .devices offhand, but the current version doesn't.
